# Photoshop "Pucker Tool" algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, photoshop, effect

Could someone tell me what the name of this effect applied by the "Pucker Tool" in Photoshop? I need to deflate the characters that come in this captcha.

The algorithm used or a Java class, would be very welcome too.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You wouldn't be trying to defeat captcahs for Evil Purposes, would you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly a fancy algorithm, but a simple distortion. As @Erwald points out, it's moving pixels towards the center of the brush iteratively.

So, if we wanted to implement this, we would need a distortion field to map output pixels to input pixel positions to sample from.

so, for each output coordinate (x,y), define the resultant color:

c' = sample( f([x,y]) )

where sample takes a linear or otherwise interpolated value from the input image at the given coordinate (which may be fractional))

The characteristics you're looking for are:

1. Pixels towards the center of the output are pulled from pixels further from the outside (pulling the image inwards)
2. Rotational symmetry
3. The effect should fall off with distance (outside a certain radius, the input location is the same as the output location)
4. The effect should taper off smoothly at the edge, but not have infinite extent
5. In the center, no side should sample from the other side of the filter (it can't squish too much in the center or it'll come out all weird)

The exact equation is an exercise left to the reader :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Andrew Pouliot.

Answer (score 1):

Not to sure if it is really considered an algorithm ...

> **Pucker tool**  Moves pixels toward the center of the brush area as you hold down the mouse button or drag.